# Cors problem with Firebase Stripe extension

Tags: firebase, vue.js, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

I am trying to build an app in vue 3 with Firebase and the stripe extension.
I encounter a cors problem when i want to open a customer portal using a cloud function.

here is the code in my vue app

```js
<script>
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";

export default {
  props: ["subscription"],

  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    async openCustomerPortal() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      const functions = getFunctions();
      const functionRef = httpsCallable(
        functions,
        "ext-firestore-stripe-payments-createPortalLink"
      );
      const { data } = await functionRef({
        returnUrl: window.location.origin,
      });
      window.location.assign(data.url);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I found in the firebase doc that you need to write the location as the second parameter of the getfunction like this `const functions = getFunctions(firebaseApp, "location");`

I get a little confused at how to get the firebaseApp instance. I try to import it from my firebase.js file where the config is but somehow it is not right.

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer :
In my code, i missed an import `import { firebaseApp } from "../firebase";`
wich import the firebaseApp instance from my firebase.js configuration file.

The entire code that works now is the following :

```js
<script>
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";
import { firebaseApp } from "../firebase";

export default {
  props: ["subscription"],

  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    async openCustomerPortal() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      const functions = getFunctions(firebaseApp, "europe-west6");
      const functionRef = httpsCallable(
        functions,
        "ext-firestore-stripe-payments-createPortalLink"
      );
      const { data } = await functionRef({
        returnUrl: window.location.origin,
      });
      window.location.assign(data.url);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```